# How to exit a mobile navigation with clicking an empty area

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a working mobile navigation menu. When you click the hamburger icon menu is opening but with this piece of Javascript code, you are only able to leave the navigation menu with pressing X icon on top right. I need to exit with tapping right empty area. How can I achieve this purpose?

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0";
   document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "block";
      document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "-3000px";
  document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "none";
   document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.form-control-borderless {
  border: none;
}

.form-control-borderless:hover, .form-control-borderless:active, .form-control-borderless:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid #5d5d5c;
}

.bottom-nav-item .bottom-nav-link a {
 color:#fff;
 font-size:10px;
 font-weight:bold;
}

/* The side navigation menu */
.sidenav {
  height: 100%; /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 100%; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1050; /* Stay on top */
  top: 0; /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  background-color: #1c1919; /* Black*/
  transition: 0.5s; /* no transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  width: 75%;
}

/* The navigation menu links */
.sidenav a {
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    font-weight: 600;
    transition: 0.3s;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */
.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}

/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */
.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */
#main {
  transition: margin-left .5s;
  padding: 20px;
}

/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */
@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}

#kapatici {
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #fff;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <section class="clean-block clean-info dark" style="background-color: #141414;padding-bottom: 10px;">
          
                <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin-top: 15px;">
                    <div class="col text-left" style="background-color: #ffa300;padding: 5px;padding-right: 4px;border-radius: 3px;"><a href="#" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);padding-left: 14px;font-weight: 600;">Bahis Yap</a></div>
                </div>
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
                    <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;border-radius: 3px;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:  #ffa300;font-size: 25px;"></i><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;font-size: 16;"><strong><em>Canlı</em></strong> Bahis</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end"
                            style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i></div>
                </div>
    
  <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="left:-3000px;">  
       
  <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"> <span id="kapatici" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span></div>
    <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
                    <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;"><img src="assets/img/futboltopu.png" style="width: 32px;height: 26px;"><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">Futbol</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i></div>
                </div>
                <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
                    <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;"><img src="assets/img/basketboltopu.png" style="width: 32px;height: 26px;"><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">Basketbol</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i></div>
                </div>
  
                  </div>
                
  
 <nav class="bottom-nav">
      <div class="bottom-nav-item active" style="width:0;">
        <div class="bottom-nav-link">
  
        </div>
      </div>
   
     
    </nav>
    
    
                <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
                    <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;">
     <i class="fa fa-navicon" onclick="openNav()" style="color:  #ffa300;font-size: 25px;"></i>
     <a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">CLICK LEFT HAMBURGER</a>
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i>
     </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </section>
```

This is the snippet. Is it possible to clck to the right empty area so left side navigation menu can disappear?

Comment: Everything seems to be mixed up with your code. normally, the navbar can be turned off with a click event outside the nav menu, but your codes are very complex. The width and height values of the Body, html elements do not even occupy the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now let me explain to you what I did: first, I did 100% of the width of the sidebar element. I created 75% width for the menu items to appear and 25% width for the free space. Clicking on the area with 25% width will close the sidebar. To do this, you can check sidebar html and sidebar css files. I used Display-flex.

instead of giving them all black as background color, I used black on the left side and transparent on the right side.

I have to say. Their code needs to be edited. It would be better for you to review it.

```js
/* Set the width of the side navigation to 250px */
function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "0";
  document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "none";
}

/* Set the width of the side navigation to 0 */
function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.left = "-3000px";
  document.getElementById("kapatici").style.display = "none";
  document.getElementById("hamburger").style.display = "block";
}

document.getElementById("mySidenav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains("nav-right")) {
    closeNav()
  }
})
```

```css
.form-control-borderless {
  border: none;
}

.form-control-borderless:hover,
.form-control-borderless:active,
.form-control-borderless:focus {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.card {
  border: 5px solid #5d5d5c;
}

.bottom-nav-item .bottom-nav-link a {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 10px;
  font-weight: bold;
}


/* The side navigation menu */

.sidenav {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  /* 100% Full-height */
  width: 100%; /* 0 width - change this with JavaScript */
  position: fixed;
  /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 11;
  /* Stay on top */
  top: 0;
  /* Stay at the top */
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
  /* no transition effect to slide in the sidenav */
  width: 100%;
}

.sidenav .nav-left {
  width: 75%;
  background-color: #1c1919;
  /* Black*/
}

.sidenav .nav-right {
  width: 25%;
  background-color: transparent;
}


/* The navigation menu links */

.sidenav a {
  padding: 0;
  padding-top: 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 14px;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 600;
  transition: 0.3s;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}


/* When you mouse over the navigation links, change their color */

.sidenav a:hover {
  color: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Position and style the close button (top right corner) */

.sidenav .closebtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}


/* Style page content - use this if you want to push the page content to the right when you open the side navigation */

#main {
  transition: margin-left 0.5s;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* On smaller screens, where height is less than 450px, change the style of the sidenav (less padding and a smaller font size) */

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {
    padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .sidenav a {
    font-size: 18px;
  }
}

#kapatici {
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 45px;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>

  <section class="clean-block clean-info dark" style="background-color: #141414;padding-bottom: 10px;">

    <div class="row align-items-center" style="margin-top: 15px;">
      <div class="col text-left" style="background-color: #ffa300;padding: 5px;padding-right: 4px;border-radius: 3px;"><a href="#" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);padding-left: 14px;font-weight: 600;">Bahis Yap</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
      <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;border-radius: 3px;"><i class="fa fa-clock-o" style="color:  #ffa300;font-size: 25px;"></i><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;font-size: 16;"><strong><em>Canlı</em></strong> Bahis</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end"
          style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i></div>
    </div>

    <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav" style="left:-3000px;">
      <!-- nav-left -->
      <div class="nav-left">
        <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"> <span id="kapatici" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
          <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;"><img src="assets/img/futboltopu.png" style="width: 32px;height: 26px;"><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">Futbol</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mx-0 row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
          <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;"><img src="assets/img/basketboltopu.png" style="width: 32px;height: 26px;"><a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">Basketbol</a><i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- nav-right -->
      <div class="nav-right">
        <!-- empty, just space for close the navbar -->
      </div>

    </div>


    <!-- <nav class="bottom-nav">
            <div class="bottom-nav-item active" style="width:0;">
                <div class="bottom-nav-link">

                </div>
            </div>


        </nav> -->


    <div class="row d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" style="margin-top: 1px;">
      <div class="col text-left d-flex" style="padding: 5px;background-color: #242424;">
        <i class="fa fa-navicon" onclick="openNav()" style="color:  #ffa300;font-size: 25px;"></i>
        <a href="#" style="color: #d7d4d4;padding-left: 14px;">CLICK LEFT HAMBURGER</a>
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-right d-inline-flex flex-grow-1 justify-content-end" style="color: rgb(255,255,255);margin-top: 4px;text-align: right;margin-right: 5px;"></i>
      </div>
    </div>

    </div>
  </section>
```